# Visual Studio Wild Card Search?

Tags: regex, visual-studio

What would be wild card / regex to search and replace all Bind attributes:
Can following be used to search & replace all texts, in wild card notation?

> [Bind("*")]

Example:

> [Bind("Id,CategoryId,CreationTime,LastModificationTime,TagsCsv,Title")]

Comment: Regex is not the same as wildcards. `*` means` 0 or more occurrences, but `[` and `(` / `)` are special chars in regex.

Comment: Do you mean [`(\[Bind\(")[^"]+("\)\])`](https://regex101.com/r/9wYeh3/1) or [`(?<=\[Bind\(")[^"]+(?="\)])`](https://regex101.com/r/Two2mo/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
\[Bind\(\"[a-zA-Z,]*\"\)\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/fhNGOY/2